# I want to display bar with minPointLength dynamically when value in null in highchart

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have tried with following demo : I want to show bar like given image [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MgGiu.png)
When value is null i want to show bar like blue bar with minPointLength.

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F67af.png): https://jsfiddle.net/8vzxf90p/`enter code here`

Answer (score 1):

1. Use the **minPointLength** feature and use the 0 rather than the null, because the chart treats the null value like the point doesn't exist.
2. Use this custom function which iterates through the points and if the point is a null - do an update on it.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/6Laf5n9u/

```
  chart: {
    type: "column",
    height: 205,
        events: {
            load() {
                let chart = this;

                chart.series[0].points.forEach(p => {
                    if (p.y === null) {
                        p.update({
                            y: 2,
                            dataLabels: {
                                enabled: false
                            }
                        })
                    }
                })
            }
        }
  },
```

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.load

API: https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Point#update

Comment: Can we use minPointLength value inside load event when value is null?

Comment: I don't understand the concept of using the `minPointLength` inside load event. Could you reproduce it and explain what do you want to achieve?